# How do you acces SDCard Path in Unity on an Android Device?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

Trying to return the SDCard path in Unity as a string.

```
AndroidJavaObject SDPath = new AndroidJavaObject("android.os.Environment"); 
AndroidJavaObject SDPath1  = SDPath.Call<AndroidJavaObject("getExternalStorageDirectory",null);
string path_str = SDPath1.Call<string>("getAbsolutePath");
```

However it doesn't seem to be working.I try passing the string to a UI element but nothing is rendered. I've tested the UI element and that aspect of the code is working.Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also found those methods calls don't work so I now use a workaround : you can find it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983451/unity-android-save-files-disappears-after-updating-an-app/39994912#39994912). I hope it helps.

Also you have to make sure external writing is allowed.

Answer (score 3):

Edit/Fixed: A unity update made the function call ambiguous

I had the same problem and found out that the method works, but not how you would expect. "GetExternalStorageDirectory" will give you one of the available paths to external storage and in most cases, it's the path to the emulated external storage, not the sd card.

To get the path to the sd card you have to call "GetExternalStorageDirectorie**s**". This will give you a list of all available external storages, emulated and sd card.

```
    AndroidJavaObject[] externalFilesDirectories = context.Call<AndroidJavaObject[]>("getExternalFilesDirs", (object)null);
```

After that, you just have to distinguish between emulated and external storage with the java functions "isExternalStorageRemovable" and "isExternalStorageEmulated". If it's not emulated and removable you found the path to the sd card.

```
bool isRemovable = environment.CallStatic<bool>("isExternalStorageRemovable", directory); 
bool isEmulated = environment.CallStatic<bool>("isExternalStorageEmulated", directory);

// We found the sd card!
if (isRemovable && isEmulated == false) 
    return directory;
```

If you wrap this up to a function you will get something like this:

```
   private static string GetAndroidExternalFilesDir()
{
     using (AndroidJavaClass unityPlayer = 
            new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer"))
     {
          using (AndroidJavaObject context = 
                 unityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity"))
          {
               // Get all available external file directories (emulated and sdCards)
               AndroidJavaObject[] externalFilesDirectories = 
                                   context.Call<AndroidJavaObject[]>
                                   ("getExternalFilesDirs", (object)null);
               AndroidJavaObject emulated = null;
               AndroidJavaObject sdCard = null;
               for (int i = 0; i < externalFilesDirectories.Length; i++)
               {
                    AndroidJavaObject directory = externalFilesDirectories[i];
                    using (AndroidJavaClass environment = 
                           new AndroidJavaClass("android.os.Environment"))
                    {
                        // Check which one is the emulated and which the sdCard.
                        bool isRemovable = environment.CallStatic<bool>
                                          ("isExternalStorageRemovable", directory);
                        bool isEmulated = environment.CallStatic<bool>
                                          ("isExternalStorageEmulated", directory);
                        if (isEmulated)
                            emulated = directory;
                        else if (isRemovable && isEmulated == false)
                            sdCard = directory;
                    }
               }
               // Return the sdCard if available
               if (sdCard != null)
                    return sdCard.Call<string>("getAbsolutePath");
               else
                    return emulated.Call<string>("getAbsolutePath");
            }
      }
}
```