# How to get android folder paths in Unity with Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I don't use Android Studio. I am using Unity with Visual Studio to develop an app. I don't see any `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` in my `Environment` class. I've written this code but it doesn't seem to be working..

```
public void CreateDirectory()
{
    try
    {
        //Directory.CreateDirectory("/storage/emulated/0/ScratcpPadData");
        switch (storeLocation)
        {
            case Storage.Internal:
                Directory.CreateDirectory(@"/storage/sdcard0/" + CustomFolderPath.text + "/");
                filePath = "/storage/sdcard0/" + CustomFolderPath.text + "/";
                break;
            case Storage.External:
                Directory.CreateDirectory(@"/storage/sdcard1/" + CustomFolderPath.text + "/");
                filePath = "/storage/sdcard1/" + CustomFolderPath.text + "/";
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        File.Create(filePath + FileName.text);
       // File.Create()
        LogText.text = filePath + FileName.text + " is succesfully created.";
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        LogText.text = "Error: " + ex.Message.ToString();
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me why? And how can I get the android folder paths (like Internal Storage path etc.) inside Visual Studio while working with unity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround you can use can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983451/unity-android-save-files-disappears-after-updating-an-app/39994912#39994912). Make sure you have enabled *External writting* in your build settings.

*Hope this helps,*